# How to include Source Code by pointing to a File Path (recursively)

Tags: listings, minted, code, sourcecode, java

I'm looking for a way to include source code in my thesis' appendix.

Any chance to add source code by pointing to a directory and adding the java file recursively going through the packages?

I do and did already use `minted` and `listings`. Maybe I have missed a feature of these packages. But since the java source code might change, I would like to avoid copy&paste which increase the chance to miss something. Favourable it's done automatically.

Comment: I am a big fan of [listings](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/). You can use `\lstinputlisting` to include a single source file, however, this won't recursively search through a directory for you. On the other hand, I doubt that you'd want to include hundreds of files this way but even if you did it wouldn't take you long to throw together the tex code for this using a reasonable editor and a regular expression. Of course, it wouldn't automatically update...

Comment: ...the list of files

Comment: Have you seen [List all files from directory base on regex with extension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341578). You could filter by `.*\string\.java`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand on my comment, you could always do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\foreach \java in  {hello, hello} {
   \begin{figure}[htpb]
        \lstinputlisting[language=java]{\java.java}
        \caption{Source code for \textsf{\java.java}}
     \label{fig:\java}
   \end{figure}
}

\end{document}
```

with output:

[image]

This does not recursively search for files but it will update when the source files change and it does minimize what you have to type by only requiring you to add the file names to the loop.

The MWE is more for proof of concept as you'd probably want to tweak the formatting and layout of the code. Personally, I'd never use figure, or floats in general, as I like text/environments to appear where I type them:). I just checked and, as I suspected, using `figure` causes problems when the source file is too long to fit on one page.

Comment: Awesome, ok it's not going recursively through the path but I don't have to add the path for every single file in a package. :) Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasZuberbühler It looks like TeX doesn't have a native way to discover every file in a directory.  You could use a quick program of your own to write out a file with that information (or something like `\write18{ls ...}`, which would be equivalent).

Comment: @Andrew I write something like [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25618703/). but doesn't work.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal Your question is not directly related to this post which was about including many files in a uniform way. Is is also not clear what your problem is. I suggest that you ask a quetsion in which you include your full code *and* your error message *and* a description of the problem. The problem is almost certainly related to your paths but without knowing what your error message is it is hard to say.

Comment: @Andrew the problem is solved. when `\lstinputlisting` used there is no need of `\begin{lstlisting}` and `\end{lstlisting}`.

Comment: Dear @Andrew maybe you can help me with this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437220/how-to-import-java-source-code-from-multiple-folders-to-latex

I have a folder and I want to iterate through all the subfolders and find all java files, which I want to display in my document.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to include single files using minted. As documented in the package documentation.

```
\inputminted[autogobble]{C++}{myfile.cpp}
```

Use [Andrew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330401/5333) to include multiple source files.