# List all files from directory base on regex with extension

Tags: macros, listings, external-files, directory

Is there a really sophisticated method to include all files which name match specific criteria (for example all .cpp, .h files) for given path to directory?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
    \lstAllFromDirectory{directory}{*.cpp *.h}
\end{document}
```

What approach should I use in order to get result like that?

Comment: I would use simple command line techniques to create a file with the directory listing and then input that file into the latex document. Not "sophisticated", perhaps, but workable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Platform independent approach using [`texosquery`](https://ctan.org/pkg/texosquery) (requires Java):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{texosquery}

\begin{document}

\TeXOSQueryFilterFileList{\result}{,}{.*\string\.(cpp|h)}{.}

\makeatletter
\ifx\result\empty
 Query Failed!
\else
\@for\thisfile:=\result\do{%
  File: \texttt{\thisfile}.\par
}
\fi
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

It needs the shell escape. If the file is called `test.tex` then:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape test
```

With MikTeX, you also need the piped shell escape enabled (`--enable-pipes`).

There are three variants of `texosquery`:

1. `texosquery-jre5`: requires at least Java 5, but doesn't have the full set of features and is less secure;
2. `texosquery` (default): requires at least Java 7, has almost the full set of features, but certain file operations have restrictions;
3. `texosquery-jre8`: requires at least Java 8, has the full set of features, but certain file operations have restrictions, and is now on TeX Live's list of trusted applications.

So if you have Java 8 and `texosquery-jre8` is on the restricted list (which it is for TL2017) then you can use the restricted shell escape.

To switch from the default `texosquery` to `texosquery-jre8`, you need to edit the `texosquery.cfg` file. The simplest method is to copy the installed `texosquery.cfg` to your local or home TEXMF tree and edit it from there. That way it won't be overwritten when the distribution is updated.

Set `\TeXOSInvokerName` to the required application:

```
\def\TeXOSInvokerName{texosquery-jre8}
```

Uncomment the following line to allow the application to be run in restricted mode:

```
\TeXOSQueryAllowRestricted
```

(Only do this if the application is actually on the restricted list.) Now you can just do (with TeX Live):

```
pdflatex test
```

or with MikTeX:

```
pdflatex --enable-pipes test
```

Also works with plain eTeX:

```
\input texosquery

\TeXOSQueryFilterFileList{\result}{,}{.*\string\.(cpp|h)}{.}    

\ifx\result\empty
 Query Failed!
\else
 % iterate over comma-separated list stored in \result using your preferred method
\fi

\bye
```

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(code.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\texosquery\texosquery.sty"

! LaTeX Error: File `texosquery.tex' not found.

Comment: @Mr.Nimelo Sounds like something's wrong with your installation of `texosquery`. You should have both `/tex/generic/texosquery/texosquery.tex` and `/tex/latex/texosquery/texosquery.sty`.

Comment: How can i fix installation? I tried to uninstall -> install again

Comment: Can you check if `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\texosquery\texosquery.tex` exists? If it's not there then that sounds like there's a problem with the way MikTeX installs it. You can manually create the `texosquery.tex` file. Download [`texosquery.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/texosquery/texosquery.dtx) and [`texosquery.ins`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/texosquery/texosquery.ins) and do `pdflatex texosquery.ins`.

Comment: Well it still doesn't work properly. My distribution of TeX installed this package inside floowing directory C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex. Is a way to add it manually?

Comment: @Mr.Nimelo I've edited my answer.