# Iterate through files in specific directory

Tags: expl3, external-files

While trying to enhance one of my packages, I wondered whether it is possible to iterate through a directory's file list in expl3 (I've read in `l3interfaces.pdf` that expl3 has some IO facilities, but they seem unable to scan directories).

The use case is the following: I have one main document. This shall include some special files generated with an external application and stored in directories outside the path.

So the question is: How would an `expl3` "directory scanner" (I only want to specify the directory) look or do I have to use Lua for this purpose?

Comment: I assume that you specify only the directory?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341578/list-all-files-from-directory-base-on-regex-with-extension.  TeX/LaTeX isn't really designed to work with directories

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Does not sound bad, but I'd rather use a TeXy approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`expl3` is written in tex so is limited to the facilities that tex provides so you can not do this unless you use  `-shell-escape` or luatex.

For example this will typeset a list of tex files in the current directory if that is what `ls *.tex` generates in your operating system. (probably `dir *.tex` in windows)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newread\zzz

\begin{document}

\def\zzpar{\par}

\openin\zzz="|ls *tex"
\loop
\read\zzz to \tmp
\ifx\tmp\zzpar\else
\par[\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\tmp}]%
\fi
\ifeof\zzz\else
\repeat

\end{document}
```

If I run it I get 105 pages looking like

[image]

Comment: How would a version with `--shell-escape` look like (command line tools or what do you mean)?

Comment: @TeXnician added an example

Comment: With miktex you need (only) `--enable-pipes` and the command should be `dir /w/B *.tex`  (and it stopped for me after 6 pages with a runaway argument: my test folder is a garbage heap -- no orderly numbered zz or yy files -- and sometimes in the dark ages I managed to create a file `{foo.tex` ...)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, it really works well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I'll accept it again as it is now real multi-platform.

Comment: @TeXnician egreg will be so pleased!

Answer (score 4):

With TeX Live 2017 an enhanced version of TeXOSQuery will be shipped, which also runs in the restricted shell:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{texosquery}

\TeXOSQuery{\result}{-i ; .}

\show\result

\stop
```

This outputs

```
> \result=macro:
->dl.log;dl.tex;install-tl;LICENSE.CTAN;LICENSE.TL;osq.log;osq.tex;qrp.log;qrp.
pdf;qrp.tex;query.aux;query.log;query.pdf;query.tex;rand.log;rand.pdf;rand.tex;
release-texlive.txt;texmf-dist;texnician.log;texnician.tex;texosquery.cfg;texpu
t.log;tlpkg;tt.aux;tt.idx;tt.ilg;tt.ind;tt.log;tt.pdf;tt.tex.
```

You can then use standard methods for splitting the `\result` macro into components.

There are restrictions on what directories you can access to, for security reasons, but child directories of the working directory should be safe.

Comment: For me (on windows) \result is empty when I don't use --shell-escape. With -shell-escape it works with tl17, but not with miktex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You have to use a personal `texosquery.cfg` file, see http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-April/039884.html

Comment: Ah. I had seen this but forgotten.

Comment: Accepted David Carlisle's answer again, since it uses only shell-escape (no Java) and is "portable" now.